# openmp on for loop

Tags: c, openmp

I have the following code:

```
for(i=0; i<num1; i++)
{
 j=i%num2;
 a[j]=do_compute(j);
}
```

Let's assume num2 << num1. If I wanted to use omp for, is there any need to use j as private? i.e. as follows:

```
#pragma omp parallel private(i,j)
{
 #pragma omp for
 for(i=0; i<num1; i++)
 {
  j=i%num2;
  a[j]=do_compute(j);
 }
}
```

or would this suffice:

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
 #pragma omp for
 for(i=0; i<num1; i++)
 {
  j=i%num2;
  a[j]=do_compute(j);
 }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If j is only used in the scope of the loop, I'd do the following:

```
[...]
unsigned int i;
#pragma omp parallel for
for(i = 0; i < num1; ++i)
{
    unsigned int j = i % num2;
    a[j] = do_compute(j);
}
[...]
```

not trying to be picky here, but given that `do_compute` is deterministic and has no side-effects, you'd be better off with just using

```
[...]
unsigned int i;
#pragma omp parallel for
for(i = 0; i < num2; ++i)
    a[i] = do_compute(i);
[...]
```

Comment: If I just use "j=i%num2;" instead of "unsigned int j=i%num2;" will I have to use the "private(i,j)" part then? Thanks.

Comment: @torem **depends on what `j` is used for after the loop** didn't I make myself clear enough? You didn't give enough information to answer that.

Comment: Sorry, j is only used inside that single loop throughout the whole program. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't understand. is it used only inside the loop **or** throughout the whole program? only one is possible.

Comment: Only inside the "for" loop. Thanks.

Comment: if it's only used in the loop, then it should be declared in the loop and the private is obsolete.

Comment: If a variable is declared in the inner scope, then the `private` clause is not obsolete but rather erroneous and the compiler will complain about an undeclared identifier in the specification list.